# R shiny: display "loading..." message while function is running

Tags: r, shiny

I use Shiny GUI R package. I'm looking for a way to display a message like "loading..." after the actionButton was pressed. The function takes several minutes to execute, so I need to inform the user somehow that the button actually triggered some event. Now the server.R code looks like this:

```
DATA <- reactive({
  if(input$DownloadButton>0) {
    RunDownload()
  } else {
    NULL
  }
})

output$Download <- renderText({
  if(NROW(DATA())>0) {
    paste0(Sys.time(),": ",NROW(DATA()), " items downloaded")
  } else {
    ''
  }
})
```

`actionButton()` is a function that downloads data from internet. `input$DownloadButton` is actionButton. So after the button was pressed the user waits for several minutes and only then sees a message saying that download was successful. I would like to show a message "Loading..." just after the actionButton was pressed and then another message like `paste0(Sys.time(),": ",NROW(DATA()), " items downloaded")` when execution ends.

Comment: To simplify things I think you need a progress bar and in R there are many ways to add it to functions. Can we have a version of `RunDownload` to see how to add progress bar ?

Comment: I don't need a progress bar, well it can be called binary progress bar. I need to show 2 messages: one at function start and one at function end. I think I forgot to specify in message body that I'm using Shiny package, it's not just R code. Will fix that now.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'm already using a simpler and more reliable way than the one I posted before.

A combination of

```
tags$style(type="text/css", "
           #loadmessage {
             position: fixed;
             top: 0px;
             left: 0px;
             width: 100%;
             padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
             text-align: center;
             font-weight: bold;
             font-size: 100%;
             color: #000000;
             background-color: #CCFF66;
             z-index: 105;
           }
  ")
```

with

```
conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                 tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage")
)
```

Example:

```
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel("Test"),
         sidebarPanel(
           tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "
             #loadmessage {
               position: fixed;
               top: 0px;
               left: 0px;
               width: 100%;
               padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
               text-align: center;
               font-weight: bold;
               font-size: 100%;
               color: #000000;
               background-color: #CCFF66;
               z-index: 105;
             }
          ")),
           numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
           conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                            tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage"))
         ),
         mainPanel(plotOutput('plot'))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ Sys.sleep(2); hist(runif(input$n)) })
  }
))
```

tags$head() is not required, but it's a good practice to keep all the styles inside head tag.

Comment: Can something similar be done for `renderDataTable` tables inside the page that take some time to load?

Comment: Love this solution, but I'm having a hard time making it work with `shinydashboard`. Any ideas why? In the developer console I can see the condition getting triggered, but despite trying many different locations and wrappers around the `conditionalPanel`, I can't get the message to actually show up.

Comment: In case anyone has the same question I did, I adapted this bug-workaround to get a much nicer looking and more natural to use progress bar that works on `shinydashboard` as well: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/609

Comment: In this case, how do you use `textOutput` to replace "loading..." with a dynamic message? For example, what if I want to indicate how many rows are being crunched by the running function (e.g. "Mining 50,000 records").?

Answer (score 41):

Very simply, you can use built-in shiny functions `showModal()` at the start of the function and `removeModal()` at the end. If you remove the footer, said modal cannot be clicked out of.

Example:

```
observeEvent(input$button, {
     showModal(modalDialog("Doing a function", footer=NULL))
     #Do the stuff here....
     #...
     #...
     #Finish the function
     removeModal()
})
```

Comment: The `shinybusy` package also has a nice "busy" signal which can also be incorporated as modal dialog. I find that more attractive than just text, however it does require an additional package.

Answer (score 8):

Though this question is old I think it is still relevant. I have another solution to offer that displays the activity indicator **on the button** that starts a lengthy process next to the button label.

[image: Button with an activity indicator]

We need an action button with a label in a `span` and some way of identifying that label.

```
actionButton("btnUpdate", span("Update", id="UpdateAnimate", class=""))
```

We also need some CSS animation that can be added to the button label, e.g. like this:

```
            tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", '
            .loading {
                display: inline-block;
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 1.3em;
                margin-top: -0.3em;
                line-height: 1.5em;
                vertical-align: text-bottom;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .loading.dots::after {
                text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
                content: "⠋\\A⠙\\A⠹\\A⠸\\A⠼\\A⠴\\A⠦\\A⠧\\A⠇\\A⠏";
                animation: spin10 1s steps(10) infinite;
                animation-duration: 1s;
                animation-timing-function: steps(10);
                animation-delay: 0s;
                animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                animation-direction: normal;
                animation-fill-mode: none;
                animation-play-state: running;
                animation-name: spin10;
            }
            .loading::after {
                display: inline-table;
                white-space: pre;
                text-align: left;
            }
            @keyframes spin10 { to { transform: translateY(-15.0em); } }
            '))
```

Now we can use `shinyjs`to manipulate the `span` class which dynamically adds the animation behind the button label. We add the animation once a user presses the button:

```
    observeEvent(input$btnUpdate, { # User requests update
        # ... 

        shinyjs::addClass(id = "UpdateAnimate", class = "loading dots")
        shinyjs::disable("btnUpdate")
        
        # ...
    })
```

When the operation has finished we can remove the class from the span and end the animation:

```
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # ...
        
        Sys.sleep(1) # just for show, you probably want to remove it in a real app
        # Button settings        
        shinyjs::enable("btnUpdate")
        shinyjs::removeClass(id = "UpdateAnimate", class = "loading dots")

        # ...
    })
```

The [full code of the sample app is available as gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/SigurdJanson/e2fb39c90d46c0526829c59713f27c50).

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by adding the following code to sidebarPanel():

```
HTML('<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#DownloadButton").click(function() {
            $("#Download").text("Loading...");
          });
        });
      </script>
')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ShinyJS: https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs

When the actionButton is pressed, you can easily toggle a text component showing "loading...", and when the calculation is finished, you can then toggle this component to hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, that works fine for me. I am using the Bootstrap modal. It is shown when the execution of the function starts and is hidden again, when it ends.

> modalBusy <- function(id, title,  ...){
>
> ```
>  msgHandler =  singleton(tags$head(tags$script('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsCode",
>                                             function(message) {
>                                               console.log(message)
>                                               eval(message.code);
>                                             });'
>                                             )
>                                 )
>                       )
>
>  label_id = paste(id, "label", sep='-')
>  modal_tag <- div(id=id, 
>                class="modal hide fade", 
>                "aria-hidden"=FALSE, 
>                "aria-labelledby"=label_id, 
>                "role"="dialog", 
>                "tabindex"="-1",
>                "data-keyboard"=FALSE,
>                "data-backdrop"="static")
>  header_tag <- div(class="modal-header",
>                 h3(id=label_id, title))
>  body_tag <- div(class="modal-body",
>               Row(...))   
>  footer_tag <- div(class="modal-footer")
>  modal_tag <- tagAppendChildren(modal_tag, header_tag, body_tag, footer_tag)
>  tagList(msgHandler, modal_tag) 
> }
> ```

To show and to hide it use the functions

```
showModal <- function(id,session) {
  session$sendCustomMessage(type="jsCode",
                            list(code= paste("$('#",id,"').modal('show')"
                                             ,sep="")))
}

hideModal <- function(id,session) {
  session$sendCustomMessage(type="jsCode",
                            list(code= paste("$('#",id,"').modal('hide')"
                                             ,sep="")))
}
```

Call the showModal function before your function Call and the hideModal function afterwards!

Hope this helps.

Seb

Comment: I am unable to get this to work. @Seb Can you please share a working example. Thanks