# R shiny: display “loading…” message while table is being rendered

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

In Rstudio Shiny, I got some `renderDataTable` calls that fetch information from a database via RMySQL. Some of the queries may take a few seconds to complete, and I would like to add a "Loading..." message where the table is going to finally render while waiting.

This question is similar to this one:
[R shiny: display "loading..." message while function is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325521/r-shiny-display-loading-message-while-function-is-running)

But instead of using `$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')` as a condition, I would like to somehow condition on the status of the `renderDataTable` rendering.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the `recalculating` class instead:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton('reload', 'reload'),
    dataTableOutput('dtable_out'),
    conditionalPanel("$('#dtable_out').hasClass('recalculating')", 
        tags$div('Loading ... ')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$dtable_out <- renderDataTable({
        input$reload
        Sys.sleep(2)
        data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10])
    })

}

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Comment: thanks, I can see the "Loading ..." message appearing and disappearing adequately, but there is still a fraction of time after `recalculating` where the table still isn't displayed. Is that HTML rendering time?

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been looking for this exact thing for hours.

Answer (score 2):

Package `shinycssloaders` does the job with some pretty animations: https://github.com/andrewsali/shinycssloaders

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way (not too elegant), would be to set as condition something like "NOT the condition that you expect when rendering done".

eg. if you're expecting expectedClass:

> conditionalPanel("**!**$('#dtable_out').hasClass('expectedClass')", 
>           tags$div('Loading ... ')
>       )

Worked for me when the above didn't...