# Shiny Dashboard - display a dedicated "loading.." page until initial loading of the data is done

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have initial loading of data from the DB in the `server.R` which takes a few seconds. Until this is done, the page displayed is distorted (wrong data in selection box, and weird placing of the boxes, see below). 
[image: Distorted display]

I want to display a different page (or at least different content in my first-displayed tab) until the data is completely loaded.

I thought about doing some kind of `conditionalPanel` using a condition based on a dedicated global variable (initial_loading_done), but wherever I tried placing the `conditionalPanel` it didn't work.

This is the structure of my UI.R:

```
shinyUI(

  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Title"),
    dashboardSidebar(
       sidebarMenu(
           menuItem("Tab1", tabName = "Tab1",icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuItem("Tab2", tabName = "Tab2",  icon = icon("bar-chart-o"))
       )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
       includeCSS("custom_css.css"),
       tabItems(
           tabItem(tabName = "Tab1", 
                   fluidRow(<content>),
                   mainPanel(
                      fluidRow(<content>)
                   )
           ),
           tabItem(tabName = "Tab2",
                  fluidRow(<content>),
                  mainPanel(
                      dataTableOutput('my_data_table')  
                  )
           )
       )
    )
 )
)
```

Comment: see [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325521/r-shiny-display-loading-message-while-function-is-running)

Answer (score 27):

Here's a very simple example using [`shinyjs`](http://deanattali.com/shinyjs/) package

The idea is to create the loading "page" and the content "page" under different IDs, have the content page initially hidden, and use `show()` and `hide()` after the app is ready

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

load_data <- function() {
  Sys.sleep(2)
  hide("loading_page")
  show("main_content")
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(
    id = "loading_page",
    h1("Loading...")
  ),
  hidden(
    div(
      id = "main_content",
      "Data loaded, content goes here"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  load_data()
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: First of all - thanks! The main_content is indeed hidden and displayed after the data being loaded, which is great. But 9 out of 10 times I launch the app, the "loading_page" isn't displayed at all... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like wherever I place the first div (with the loading_page), it isn't calculated until the app data is finished loading - I tried removing the show/hide part and it is only displayed after the data is completely loaded. Is this something to do with the fact I'm using shinydashboard?

Comment: no, it doesn't matter where you place the elements.  The loading_page should show up immediately, and the other div should not show up (because it's inside a `hidden()` function), and it should only show up after the `Sys.sleep(2)` finishes running.  If you run this example code that I show, it should work 10/10 times.  It will work with a shinydashboard as well

Comment: For others Googling slow shinyapps.io initial loading times, this also appears to remedy that.

Comment: Dean's solution indeed works. Is there a way to make the transition smoother, so it fades into the loaded page rather than just disappearing to reveal the loaded one?

Comment: The show/hide functions from shinyjs have an `animate` parameter

Answer (score 10):

In `server` I like to use `reactiveValues()` to store a `setupComplete` condition. Then, when the data is loaded my `setupComplete` is set to `TRUE`.

In the `ui` we can then assess this `setupComplete` condition in a `conditionalPanel`, and only display the content (in my example the three `box()` widgets).

Here's a working example

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        actionButton(inputId = "btn_data", label = "Download"),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "output.setupComplete",
            box( title = "box1" ),
            box( title = "box2" ),
            box( title = "boc3" )
        ),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "!output.setupComplete",
                         box( title = "loading"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

    rv <- reactiveValues()
    rv$setupComplete <- FALSE

    ## simulate data load
    observe({

        if(input$btn_data){

            df <- data.frame(id = seq(1,200),
                             val = rnorm(200, 0, 1))

            ## Simulate the data load
            Sys.sleep(5)
            ## set my condition to TRUE
            rv$setupComplete <- TRUE
        }

        ## the conditional panel reads this output
        output$setupComplete <- reactive({
            return(rv$setupComplete)
        })
        outputOptions(output, 'setupComplete', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)

    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helpful! I want to display a "Loading" page until the loading is done, So created another conditionalPanel with the condition "!output.setupComplete". But it cannot evaluate the setupComplete param. What should I change in the server.r in order for it to work?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a second conditional panel that shows a 'loading' box before the data is loaded. If you want to start doing more complex operations I recommend using @daattali 's excellent `shinyjs` package (as referenced in his answer)

Comment: Now your example doesn't work for me - stays with "Loading" and doesn't change to the actual content page. When trying in my app, I see the box until the data is loaded - but don't see its content (just an empty box). Pretty sure it has something to do with the location of the conditionalPanel in my code - it is inside a tabItem.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
hidden(
    div(
      id = "main_content",
      "Data loaded, content goes here"
    )
```

doesn't work with tabsetPanel. But if you move the id to the div level it works beautifully. Thanks to shinyjs author Dean Attali for this tip. https://stackoverflow.com/users/4432127/keshete

```
  hidden(
        div(id = "mainTabsetPanel",
          tabsetPanel(
....
```