# Shiny and R: load data only once - do not load at each start of app and have progress bar

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am loading somewhat large data files in the `global.R`file of my shiny-app on a shiny-server. The advantage of loading it in the `global.R`file is that it only loads once - not for every user again (if I understand correctly). However, the disadvantage is that way the apps takes around 10 seconds to start and I have no way to show a progress bar or anything. Does anybody know how to solve this issues?

Is there a way to save a workspace for ShinyApps? That way the data would not have to be loaded by `load(...)`.

Comment: Have you tried shiny_prerendered? In this way you can do a one time server-start set of actions which can include loading data and keeping in cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the progress bar, you can use the shinyjs package to hide/show components. See for example this link [Shiny Dashboard - display a dedicated "loading.." page until initial loading of the data is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599470/shiny-dashboard-display-a-dedicated-loading-page-until-initial-loading-of)