# Print console text output in shiny synchronously

Tags: r, shiny

I recently ran into a problem that as my computing took lots of time, I'd like to show the text output on shiny rather than progress bar or loading message. My function looked like

```
printText <- function() {
  for(i in 1:10){
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    print(paste("My text", i))
    y = i + 1
  }
  return(y)
}
```

I can print it with `verbatimTextOutput` but I also need the returned value of y. Now I am doing this:

```
runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Print consol output"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(actionButton("go", "Go")),
      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("text")
      )
    )
  )),
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$go, {
      output$text <- renderPrint({
          y <- printText()
      })
    })
  })
))
```

The problem is that if I want to use the returned y I need to create a `reactive` object, which may take me 2 times longer because I execute `printText()` twice, while printing and pass to `reactive` object.

How could I get the value of y and print the text onto shiny without duplicated work? Notice that I'm not gonna use progress bar because my real function is not loop actually. What I want is to capture the text output during the process and get returned value.

Comment: There are two parts of the question: 1) console output: do you want these to be displayed to the shiny interface in real time (I did a little research and it seems to be quite difficult to do so)? 2) returned value: You only need the returned value after the long calculation right? I think you can probably use a global variable.

Comment: @warmoverflow 1) I've searched for a while and found nothing:( 
2) you are right. Using global variable is a good idea.

Comment: For 1, best solution I found is to use Javascript to update the page. See here for an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325521/r-shiny-display-loading-message-while-function-is-running/22076307#22076307

Answer (score -1):

You can do this way :

ui.r

```
textOutput("id")
```

server.r

```
output$id<-renderText(input$y)
```